# Can VS Code debug older .NET C# code? (older than .NET 5)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, debugging

I have an old C# code (.NET 4.0) that I'd developed a long time ago using Visual Studio 2010 or so. I made it to be compatible with [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/), which back in the day was the best available .NET option in linux (as far as I knew).

I have now migrated to VS Code, and successfully got the code running with the standard Microsoft C# extensions (`C#`, `C# Dev Kit`, `.NET Install Tool`, `IntelliCode for C# Dev Kit`).

The problem is with debug. I made some tests and realized that VS Code cannot debug (although it builds and publishes) `x64` codes and neither it can debug codes for platform `net4.6.1` (see below for examples with comments of working and not working `launch.json`, `tasks.json` and the `*.csproj` file).

The program builds, runs, and at the end of the run, instead of hitting the breakpoint, the following message appears:

```
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[10908] KTzV2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I'm assuming I have the proper runtimes and SDKs (see the end of my question for the versions I have available), and the proper development tools, but I could be wrong.

- Is there a workaround this issue?

or

- am I missing something about VS Code that could make it debug older .NET codes?

*PS:* My code compiles in `.NET 8.0` and Microsoft now released ubuntu `.NET 8.0` SDKs and runtimes. However, Mono is not the only reason I'd target `.NET 4.6.1`. I'm also relying on some [external dependencies](https://github.com/mahalex/MatFileHandler) that target this framework.

---

- `launch.json` file

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "launch",
                "preLaunchTask": "build debug",
                //// the line below works, since it is the output of the x86-net8.0 build
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net8.0/KTzV2.dll",
                //// the line below doesn't work, since it is the output of the x86-net4.6.1 build
                //"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net4.6.1/KTzV2.exe", //
                //// the line below also doesn't work, since it is the output of the x64-net4.6.1 build
                //"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/x64/Debug/net4.6.1/KTzV2.exe", //
                "args": [],
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "console": "internalConsole",
                "stopAtEntry": false
            },
            {
                "name": ".NET Core Attach",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "attach"
            }
        ]
    }
```

- `tasks.json` file:

```
    {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "build debug",
                "command": "dotnet",
                "type": "process",
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/KTzV2.sln",
                    "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                    "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary;ForceNoAlign",
                    "--no-self-contained",
                    "--configuration",
                    "Debug",
                    //// adding here:
                    //"--arch:x64"
                    //// stops debugging from working
                ],
                "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
            },
            // [... other build tasks, such as "publish"]
        ]
    }
```

- `KTzV2.csproj` file (copied from the Visual Studio 2010-ish generated `csproj` file:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains(Debug))">
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <!--
        replacing the line above with the one below stops
        debugger from working (changing to this line
        must also change the "program" directive in the launch.json file
          <TargetFramework>net4.6.1</TargetFramework>
        -->
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <!--
        the following options stop debugger from working
        although they were copied from the original csproj file
        generated by Visual Studio 2010-ish
            <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
            <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
            <DebugType>full</DebugType> <!-- no error message -->
        -->
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="MatFileHandler" Version="1.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    </Project>
```

---

My VS Code version is

> Version: 1.87.2 (system setup)
> Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
> Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
> Electron: 27.3.2
> ElectronBuildId: 26836302
> Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
> Node.js: 18.17.1
> V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Here are my `dotnet --list-runtimes` (all installed with `vs_installer.exe` 2022 from Microsoft website with default parameters).

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

and my `dotnet --list-sdks`

```
3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5, not the next version of .NET Framework. VS Code supports .NET Core. If you want to debug .NET Framework applications (whose oldest supported version is 4.6.2) you should use VS Community Edition

Comment: if you want to debug, don't you need to install the *SDK*s, not just the runtimes? In doubt, you can download specific .NET SDKs from microsoft website. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks (see also section "Out of support versions" on the link)

Comment: The `MatFileHandler` package you are referencing also targets .NET Standard 2.0, which mean it will work just fine with .NET 8.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so, basically not possible to debug with VS Code? I also have the .NET Core 3.1 and 2.1

Comment: `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>` that's a .NET Core version too. The oldest supporte .NET Core version is .NET 6. 2.1 and 3.1 reached End Of Life years ago